# How can I index mapped network drive on windows server 2008/2012?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-search, network-drive

I am trying to index  a **mapped network drive** on **windows server 2008**. I have already enabled **windows search service**.

I saw this link

[Is there a way to get Windows 7 to index shared network drives?](https://superuser.com/questions/97991/is-there-a-way-to-get-windows-7-to-index-shared-network-drives)

but I cannot follow the same procedure on 2008 as I don't see "Add UNC location" tab on my machine.

Is there a way to index a mapped network drive on **windows server 2008**?

Answer (score 0):

If the other computer is windows Server You can install

- A. [Windows search service](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2786629)
- B. Index the files on that Computer

Then mapping to the folder will become easier.